# Concat 2 varchars in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to produce a varchar(20) which is 4 character year + 2 character month. I would like to then use this as a parameter in my stored procedure. Im unable to concatenate 2 varchars together to produce this, any ideas?

```
SELECT 
    GETDATE() AS CurrentDateTime,
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), YEAR(GETDATE())) AS CurrentYear,
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), MONTH(GETDATE())) AS CurrentMonth,
    CurrentYear + CurrentMonth AS YearMonth
```

Comment: The Column aliases aren't available in the select list. Either do the converts one more time, or wrap it up in a derived table.

Comment: `Im unable to concatenate` you mean have an error?  Then post the error. Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: Your varchar values look to be excessively large here. No need for 20 characters to hold 4 or 2 characters. There are no years longers than 4 characters and no months longer than 2, :)

Comment: What do you mean by *I would like to then use this as a parameter in my stored procedure*? It is - in general - better to keep parameters typesafe. Why convert it to a string format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this one?

```
SELECT GETDATE() AS CurrentDateTime
 , Convert(VARCHAR(20),YEAR(GETDATE())) AS CurrentYear
 , Convert(VARCHAR(20),MONTH(GETDATE())) AS CurrentMonth
 , Convert(VARCHAR(20),YEAR(GETDATE())) + Convert(VARCHAR(20),MONTH(GETDATE())) AS YearMonth
```

Also you can

```
Year(GetDate()) * 100 + Month(GateDate()) AS YearMonth
```

or use construction which offered by users below

```
Convert(varchar(6), GETDATE(), 112) AS YearMonth
```

Comment: All of these transactions are returning a yearmonth combo. Im trying to use this as a sql parameter value without returning these variables.

Comment: @jon.nicholssoftware.com  You should really just use `convert(varchar(6), gatdate(), 112)` instead of doing two conversions and then concatenating the results.

Comment: This answer has got the acceptance, but there are far better solutions... (e.g. @Squirrel with `Convert(varchar(6), GETDATE(), 112)`)

Comment: Btw: Did you check your solution with a month between January and September (OP: *+ 2 character month*)? @jon.nicholssoftware.com. Be aware of wrong output with months <10

Answer (score 6):

The simplest approach would be to use this:

```
SELECT Format(GetDate(), 'yyyyMM') as YearMonth
```

The function `Format()` was [introduced with Sql Server 2012](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505.aspx).

Comment: +1 I dig the Format() function as well, but the performance on large sets is horrible.  https://sqlperformance.com/2015/06/t-sql-queries/format-is-nice-and-all-but

Answer (score 3):

why not simply

```
SELECT GETDATE() AS CurrentDateTime
 , Convert(VARCHAR(20),YEAR(GETDATE())) AS CurrentYear
 , Convert(VARCHAR(20),MONTH(GETDATE())) AS CurrentMonth
 , Convert(varchar(6), GETDATE(), 112) AS YearMonth
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT GETDATE() AS CurrentDateTime
, Convert(VARCHAR(20),YEAR(GETDATE())) +
Convert(VARCHAR(20),MONTH(GETDATE()))
```

Column aliases can't be selected from, so the above would do.

Comment: What about months January 'til September (OP: *+ 2 character month*)?